# Fundamental group of the complement homogeneous variety in $\mathbb{C}P^{n-1}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

Let $f,g:\mathbb{C}^n\to \mathbb{C}$ are two irreducible homogeneous polynomials. If there is a homeomorphism $h:\mathbb{C}^n\to \mathbb{C}^n$ such that $h(X)=Y$ and $h(0)=0$, where $X=f^{-1}(0)$ and $Y=g^{-1}(0)$, then is true that $\pi_1(\mathbb{C}P^{n-1}\setminus X^*)$ is isomorphic the $\pi_1(\mathbb{C}P^{n-1}\setminus Y^*)$? (here $\pi_1$ denotes the first fundamental group and $A^*$ is the image of $A$ by canonical projection $p:\mathbb{C}^n\setminus\{0\}\to \mathbb{C}P^{n-1}$).

Comment: Do you worry that your homeomorphism may not take a generator of $\pi_1(\Bbb C^*)$ to a similar class?

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev, sorry, I did not understand, but $h$ can not be homogeneous complex.

Comment: I suggest you have a look at Dimca's book "Singularities and the Topology of Hypersurfaces", which has a chapter on fundamental groups of hypersurface complements.

Comment: Am I missing something? Doesn't $h$ induce a homeomorphism $\mathbb{CP}^{n-1} \to \mathbb{CP}^{n-1}$ that sends $X^*$ to $Y^*$, so induce a homeomorphism on the complements?

Comment: @LennartMeier, how $h$ induce a homeomorphism $\mathbb{CP}^{n-1} \to \mathbb{CP}^{n-1}$ that sends $X^*$ to $Y^*$? because $h$ and $h^{-1}$ are only continous.